# Are there some references to periodic Hartree-Fock calculation?

Tags: quantum-chemistry

I want to learn Hartree-Fock(HF) calculation for periodic system, but didn't find some reference. And also have some confusion about it now.

In one book(Quantum Chemistry of Solids: The LCAO First Principles Treatment of Crystals), the expression of bloch atomic orbital is below, they say the summation can make over the inner primitive translations of the cyclic cluster (in the cyclic model of a crystal), I don't know why(if most part of an atomic orbital is out of the cyclic cluster, how to deal with it?)

$\chi_{\mu \boldsymbol{k}}(\boldsymbol{r})=\frac{1}{\sqrt{N}} \sum_{\boldsymbol{R}_{n}} \exp \left(\mathrm{i} \boldsymbol{k} \boldsymbol{R}_{n}\right) \chi_{\mu}\left(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{R}_{n}\right)$

Then the book give the overlap in periodic HF $S_{\mu \nu}(\boldsymbol{k})=\sum_{\boldsymbol{R}_{n}} \exp \left(\mathrm{i} \boldsymbol{k} \boldsymbol{R}_{n}\right) S_{\mu \nu}\left(\boldsymbol{R}_{n}\right)$ with $S_{\mu \nu}\left(\boldsymbol{R}_{n}\right)=\int \chi_{\mu}^{*}(\boldsymbol{r}) \chi_{\nu}\left(\boldsymbol{r}-\boldsymbol{R}_{n}\right) d^{3} \boldsymbol{r}$
but i don't know why.

Maybe a comprehensive paper is better.
Help!